# How to find out which threading model a DLL was built with?

Tags: asp.net, com, multithreading

Writing a ASP.NET website, we have a lot of legacy components we need to rely on.

My view is that because we are MTA (Multi Threaded Apartment) in ASP.NET, if we use a STA component then the requests will queue.  So even if we use a .NET component which is MTA, if IT relies on an old STA component, this will still queue.  Am I right so far?

Anyway, my real question is - **By examining a .DLL ONLY, can I find out which threading model it was built under?**

Thanks
Duncan

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for the requirement to examine the DLL only? As far as I know, there's no programmatic metadata available for you to ask for the threading model of its contained objects -- that information is available in the registry.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  If a component ISN'T registered in the registry, for example it is just an ActiveX DLL - does this have a separate threading model?  Or is this just for COM objects?

Answer (score 1):

ActiveX and COM are basically the same thing -- they must both be registered in order to be used. Threading models (as far as I know) only apply to COM objects, not .NET objects, so unless you're doing COM interop you shouldn't need to care about threading models.

Comment: oops, I meant for that to be a comment response, but I suppose it was time for an answer :-)